# JSONPath - Filter expression is not working as expected

Tags: python, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

Can't get a JSONPath to work.

JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "definition": {
          "title": "ID",
          "type": "text",
          "key": "657876498"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "id": "8606798",
        "name": "ID",
        "content": {
          "value": "ABC"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Path:

`$.data[*].attributes[?(@.name=='ID')]`

Which returns no match on [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com/) or using `jsonpath-ng` in python.

What am I fundamentally missing that this filter isn't working?

Note: End goal would be to get `name` and `content.value`.

EDIT:

On https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ the path actually works. hm...implementation dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this seems to be an idiosyncrasy of the jsonpath-ng implementation. It looks like the ["filter op can only be used on lists"](https://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/issues/30#issuecomment-561859377), i.e. an iterable.

As a workaround, we can filter on the `data`-array and pull the `attributes` afterward instead:

```
$.data[?(@.attributes.name="ID")].attributes
```

This gives the same result as Jayway's JsonPath using your path; however, this approach may not be satisfactory in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below paths for `name` and `content.value`

```
$.data[:0].attributes.name
$.data[:0].attributes.content.value
```

Comment: And where is the filter? the issue is the filter as that is relevant

Comment: $.data[?(@.attributes.name=="ID")] I thought End goal is to get the values. @buran already provided the filter details.